# `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am facing this problem:

> `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument

I am working on Expo GO (version Expo: 45.0.0) on IOS. The problem is when I import the following two libraries:

```
import { utils } from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import vision from '@react-native-firebase/ml-vision';
```

I am using:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.9.3",
"@react-native-firebase/ml-vision": "^7.4.13",
```

Comment: Have you tried posting your question in React Native Firebase's main support channel on github (https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/new/choose)?